# Can this be done in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to the world of XSLT, so please bear with me.
I have an XML output of a web service with the following structure:

```
<NotificationListResponse>
    <MessageReceiver ID=15>
        <Services>
          <Service ID=40>
              <...Other Tags Per Service ...>
          </Service>
          <Service ID=38>
              <...Other Tags Per Service ...>
          </Service>
        </Services>
    </MessageReceiver>
    <MessageReceiver ID=18>
        <Services>
          <Service ID=40>
              <...Other Tags Per Service ...>
          </Service>
          <Service ID=38>
              <...Other Tags Per Service ...>
          </Service>
        </Services>
    </MessageReceiver>
</NotificationListResponse>
```

And I would like to transform this into something like this:

```
<NotificationListResponse>
    <Services>
        <Service ID=40>
           <Receivers>
             <MessageReceiver ID=15>
               <...Other Tags Per Service ...>
             </MessageReceiver>
             <MessageReceiver ID=18>
               <...Other Tags Per Service ...>
             </MessageReceiver>
           </Receivers> 
          </Service>
          <Service ID=38>
           <Receivers>
             <MessageReceiver ID=15>
               <...Other Tags Per Service ...>
             </MessageReceiver>
             <MessageReceiver ID=18>
               <...Other Tags Per Service ...>
             </MessageReceiver>
           </Receivers> 
          </Service>
    </Services>
</NotificationListResponse>
```

I hope this is clear enough. What I want to do is make the segmentation by service, where in the web service response, the main segmentation is by the receiving party.

Can this even be done in XSLT without deserilizing the XML in to objects and doing the transform in code? Our main programming language is C#, in case that is relevant.

Comment: The answer is positive. Search for Muenchian grouping, or read this directly: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe, a bit wordy and can be improved, but works through msxsl in c#. as others have said, just a different way of looking at grouping:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:template match="/NotificationListResponse">
            <NotificationListResponse>
            <Services>
                <xsl:for-each select=".//Service">
                    <xsl:variable name="id" select="@ID"/>
                    <xsl:if test="count(preceding::Service[$id]) &lt; 2">
                        <Service ID="{$id}">
                            <Receivers>
                                <xsl:for-each select="//Service[@ID=$id]">
                                    <MessageReciever>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="ID">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::MessageReceiver/@ID"/>
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                                    </MessageReciever>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </Receivers>
                        </Service>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Services>
            </NotificationListResponse>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inverting a hierarchy like this is one example of a grouping problem: because the task is to find all the MessageReceiver elements having the same ID, and group the output according to this value.

Grouping is much easier in XSLT 2.0 than in XSLT 1.0, though the answer to your headline question (can it be done?) is yes in both cases. However, the solutions are very different, so it would help to know which version you are using.

Logically the pseudo-code for the solution is the same in both cases:

```
<for each group of Service elements grouped by ID>
  <Service ID=ID>
    <for each Service in the group>
      <process the ancestor MessageReceiver/>
    </
  </
</
```

In XSLT 2.0 look for the `<xsl:for-each-group>` element. In XSLT 1.0, look for tutorials on "Muenchian grouping"